# incompatibles types error using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Java streams,

So I took this example and I'm getting a compilation error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
public class JavaApplication14 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);list.add(2);list.add(3);
    list.add(6);list.add(5);list.add(4);
    List<Integer> l = list.stream().filter(i->i%2==0).collect(Collectors.toList());

 }
}
```

Could someone say why I'm getting this error in the last line of code:

```
List<Integer> l = list.stream().filter(i->i%2==0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your code should compile fine.

Comment: I have run your code in my local environment and it runs fine, no errors. Is your environment configured to compile with JDK8?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You use List interface, where is import java.util.List; ?

Comment: thank you for the help , i resolved my issue,a bad import statement was the source of the problem.

Comment: @Worthless could you make it as an awnser ,thanks.

Comment: so when i should import the good List  interface , by mistake i created a new class List in my package.for that reason i get a compilation error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used List interface, but didn't import it.

```
import java.util.List;
```